# I want to start Making mods in minecraft and I have a problem when i am trying to run Gradlew setupDecompWorkspace it gives me a error

Tags: minecraft, gradlew

When I open powershell I typed ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace it gives me that

````
* What went wrong:
Task 'setupDecompWorkspace' not found in root project 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859-mdk'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
PS C:\Users\Ostrov\Desktop\Minecraft Mod Creation\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859-mdk>```

It says BUILD FAILED in 8s because I tried to install it and it installed it for a few minutes but then it says there is an error and build failed
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the mdk from Forge's website?

If you're on IntelliJ, you don't have to run this command. It automatically sets up the Gradle project. You should get a UI that looks like this:

[image: Gradle menu on IntelliJ]

Now, instead of typing the command, you can just click genIntellijRuns under the fg_runs section of the Gradle menu.